# Dataframe to .csv - is only writing last value - Python/Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to write a dataframe to a .csv using df.to_csv(). For some reason, its only writing the last value (data for the last ticker). It reads through a list of tickers (turtle, all tickers are in first column) and spits out price data for each ticker. I can print all the data without a problem but can't seem to write to .csv. Any idea why? Thanks

```
input_file = pd.read_csv("turtle.csv", header=None)

for ticker in input_file.iloc[:,0].tolist():
    data = web.DataReader(ticker, "yahoo", datetime(2011,06,1),     datetime(2016,05,31))
    data['ymd'] = data.index
    year_month = data.index.to_period('M')
    data['year_month'] = year_month
    first_day_of_months = data.groupby(["year_month"])["ymd"].min()
    first_day_of_months = first_day_of_months.to_frame().reset_index(level=0)
    last_day_of_months = data.groupby(["year_month"])["ymd"].max()
    last_day_of_months = last_day_of_months.to_frame().reset_index(level=0)
    fday_open = data.merge(first_day_of_months,on=['ymd'])
    fday_open = fday_open[['year_month_x','Open']]
    lday_open = data.merge(last_day_of_months,on=['ymd'])
    lday_open = lday_open[['year_month_x','Open']]

    fday_lday = fday_open.merge(lday_open,on=['year_month_x'])
    monthly_changes = {i:MonthlyChange(i) for i in range(1,13)}

    for index,ym, openf,openl in fday_lday.itertuples():
            month = ym.strftime('%m')
            month = int(month)
            diff = (openf-openl)/openf
            monthly_changes[month].add_change(diff)

    changes_df = pd.DataFrame([monthly_changes[i].get_data() for i in monthly_changes],columns=["Month","Avg Inc.","Inc","Avg.Dec","Dec"])

    CSVdir = r"C:\Users\..."
    realCSVdir = os.path.realpath(CSVdir)

    if not os.path.exists(CSVdir):
        os.makedirs(CSVdir)

    new_file_name = os.path.join(realCSVdir,'PriceData.csv')
    new_file = open(new_file_name, 'wb')

    new_file.write(ticker)
    changes_df.to_csv(new_file)
```

Comment: instead of `wb` use `a` for appending.

Comment: you're overwriting your 'PriceData.csv' CSV file in loop... I would also suggest you to post a sample of your desired CSV file - I think it can be done much easier...

Comment: .@Rage. I would recommending looking  up  python tutorials before posting more questions. ---- the above code use the 'for-loop' incorrectly. for setting the date information.

Comment: @ Merlin, Are you talking about this part of the code:

Comment: for index,ym, openf,openl in fday_lday.itertuples():
            month = ym.strftime('%m')
            month = int(month)
            diff = (openf-openl)/openf
            monthly_changes[month].add_change(diff)

Answer (score 2):

Use `a` for appending instead of `wb` because it overwrites the data in every iteration of loop.For different modes of opening a file see [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm).